# Computer is randomly shutting down. What could be?

Tags: boot, shutdown, gui, acpi

I'm having some problems, my computer is shutting down at random intervals, but from today it started to shut off rigth after the login screen.

It's a Toshiba Laptop. I thought it was the cpu overheating, but it's not. I tried also different RAMs and it won't work either.

Then I was thinking that it could be related to the ACPI but I tried adding the "acpi=off" in the boot/kernel and it shut off again.

So I really have no idea about what's happening. I still can boot in recovery mode but with the CLI only, as soon as I issue "startx" it'll shut down, sometimes instantly and other times after 1 o 2 minutes.

Other thing I tried was booting live from an USB drive. It also shut down, after the GUI showed and the drive lost its booting capabilities.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please tell what Toshiba laptop it is? Please give as much detail as possible (eg: it has a Hybrid graphics system intel + dedicated gpu) What version of Ubuntu are you using? 32 or 64 bit? Please answer and I will be able to give you a better answer to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the CPU *overheating*, but still the CPU. What you describe is *exactly* what I experienced a couple of weeks ago. I then ran memtest and everything, even plugged in a graphics card (as prior to boot the screen was messed up, sometimes instead of shutting down it simply froze). Finally I booted from several CDs to make sure it was not the installation messed up. Trying with a Linux Mint 12 CD lying around, it booted in text mode and there it was: The big error message which never made it into any log file, CPU0 being out of sync, kernel panic. So try booting from a CD and see what is displayed on the console (I didn't see that when booting from the hard disk into recovery mode of Ubuntu, but that may have been sheer accident).

Comment: And how did you fix it? did you get a new CPU?